# The right way to set object properties

Tags: php, arrays, object, methods, properties

I know the question is kinda controversial, but anyway:
Let's say I have a simple class:

```
class A {
    private $a;
    private $b;

    function __construct($data = array()){
        if($data) $this->setAll($data);
    }

    function setAll($array){
        foreach ($array as $key => $value){
            if ( property_exists ( $this , $key ) ){
                $this->{$key} = $value;
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }

    function setAllByFunctions($array){
       foreach ($array as $key => $value){
            $method_name = "set".$key;
            if ( method_exists ( $this ,  $method_name) ){
                $this->$method_name($value);
            }
        }
    }

    function setA($value){
         $this->a = $value;
         return $this;
    }
    function setB($value){
        $this->b = $value;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

What is the best way to set the object properties considering the real class can have much more properties? What are the pros and cons? Is there any article I could read about that? I wasn't able to google anything useful.

1)

```
$a1 = new A();
$val = Array("A" => "value of a", "B" => "value of b");
$a1->setAll($val);
```

2)

```
$a2 = new A();
$a2->setA("value of a")->setB("value of b");
```

3)

```
$val = Array("A" => "value of a", "B" => "value of b");
$a3 = new A($val);
```

4)

```
$a4 = new A($val);
$val = Array("A" => "value of a", "B" => "value of b");
$a1->setAllByFunctions($val);
```

Comment: What's the difference between #1 and #4? Where is the definition of `setAllByFunctions()`?

Comment: Oops, sorry, Didn't paste the last version of the code. #4 is basically the same as #1 except we're using methods to set the properties instead of setting them directly.